# SQL query to find total sale per month - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I've two tables, products(pid, pname, quantityinhand, price, discount)
purchases(pid, qty, p_time, total_price) // where qty is number of units sold.
I need to find pname, pdate(in mon yyyy format), total quantity sold for each pid in a particular month, total price of the product sold in a month, average price(total_price/quantity).

Query I try is as follows

```
select pname, p_time, qty_month, amount_month, avg_sale 
FROM 
  ( select p.pname, to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy') p_time, 
            sum(qty) as qty_month, sum(total_price) as amount_month,
            (q.total_price/q.qty) as avg_sale from products p, purchases q
    where p.pid=q.pid
    group by pname, ptime)
```

I get this error -> (q.total_price/q.qty) as avg_sale from products p, purchases q

> ERROR at line 4: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.

What am I doing wrong?

I need to find monthly stats of each product in short.

By adding **"group by pname, ptime, total_price, qty"** I'm getting the results, will post another question for required procedure which takes pid as parameter and gives out monthly sale stats including pname from products table.

Comment: Can you plz provide the table structure for both the tables

Comment: instead of the alias name in group by use `to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy')` also since you are using aggregate functions you cannot use (q.total_price/q.qty) with it

Comment: SUM((q.total_price/q.qty) as avg_sale)

Comment: @PK20 thanks man, I added group by pname, ptime, total_price, qty, now need to find the same result in the form of a stored procedure taking pid as parameter and giving out monthly stats  of that particular product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT pname, 
       p_time, 
       qty_month, 
       amount_month, 
       (amount_month/qty_month) as avg_sale 
FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT   p.pname, 
             to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy') p_time, 
             sum(qty) as qty_month, 
             sum(total_price) as amount_month 
    FROM     products p, purchases q
    WHERE    p.pid=q.pid
    GROUP BY pname, to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy')
  )
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, now need to make a procedure that takes pid as parameter. Will post another question for that after trying it.

Comment: I created a procedure and it builds with no errors however when I execute it, it gives the error, error at line 1 no data found. I can't post another question for sometime, should I post it here in comments?

Comment: please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952619/sql-procedure-compiles-without-error-but-no-result-on-execution