# SQL procedure returning too many rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

I've created a procedure that takes pid as parameter and returns monthly sale stats of that pid , it uses two tables, products and purchases where pid in purchases is foreign key referencing pid in products.
The procedure builds without errors and executes well for only single row returns and otherwise give too_many_rows exception
My procedure is as follows:

```
set serveroutput on
create or replace procedure try(
p_pid in purchases.pid%type) is
p_pname products.pname%type;
p_date varchar2(10);
p_qty_monthly number(5);
p_amnt_monthly number(7,2);
p_avg_price number(7,2);


begin
select pname, p_time, qty_month, amount_month,(amount_month/qty_month) as avg_sale into p_pname,p_date,p_qty_monthly, p_amnt_monthly, p_avg_price
FROM 
    (select p.pname, to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy') p_time, 
    sum(qty) as qty_month, sum(total_price) as amount_month 
    from products p, purchases q
    where p.pid=q.pid
and q.pid= p_pid
group by pname, to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy')); 
dbms_output.put_line ('Product name is:'|| p_pname || 'Purchase date is:' || p_date || 'Units sold per month are/is: ' || p_qty_monthly || 'Monthly sale amount: ' || p_amnt_monthly || 'Average sale price is: ' || p_avg_price);
end;
/
show errors
```

It's returning more than one rows for some inputs, how can I make it print all the rows rather than give too_many_rows exception?

Comment: no data found means your select query not returning any values for handling that use exception block.

Comment: The error indicates that there are no rows in your result where the `pname` is 'p001'.  Your `select` statement is returning 0 rows.  If that is expected, you could add an exception handler to catch the `no_data_found` exception.

Comment: @JustinCave  
the query returns 11 rows in which 1 row pertains the input that I gave i.e p001

Comment: Oracle disagrees with you.  I would tend to believe Oracle and expect that you've made an error.

Comment: well when I run the query that's embedded in procedure it does return 11 tuples :D, is there any issue with "where pname=p_pname;" just before dbmsoutput line? pname is not the input for the procedure, does that matter anyhow?  @JustinCave

Comment: You're passing in a `p_pid`.  You never appear to use that parameter is your code.  Your code references a local variable `p_pname` that is never initialized so it is null.  Nothing ever equals `NULL` so, by definition, the query can't return anything.

Comment: @JustinCave when I use pid=p_pid it gives a build error saying pid is invalid identifier, how can I fix that?

Comment: Show the actual code you are using and the actual error you are getting.

Comment: I removed pname line and now getting this error at execution, builds without errors: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "xxxMyID.TRY", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 1 @JustinCave

Comment: Without a reproducible test case, it's hard to guess.  The new error implies that you're probably doing some sort of implicit data type conversion.  We don't know your table definitions, we don't know what your data looks like so we don't know where the data type conversion might be failing.

Comment: products: (pid char(4) primary key,
pname varchar2(15),
original_price number(6,2));

purchases
(pur# number(6) primary key,,
pid char(4) references products(pid),,
qty number(5),
ptime date,
total_price number(7,2)); @JustinCave

Comment: @JustinCave I also edited the procedure to display the updated one

Comment: You've changed your procedure but not the error.  You're not still getting the `no_data_found` exception I assume.  I would guess that the data type conversion happens when you try to store a string aliased to `p_time` into a variable named `p_date` which appears to be defined as a date rather than a `varchar2`.  If you fix that, I expect that you'd get a `too_many_rows` exception rather than a `no_data_found` exception.  A `select into` must return exactly 1 row.

Comment: yes some of the pids will return multiple rows, how to handle that? @JustinCave

Comment: you are right, I changed it to varchar2 and now for single row results it's working but not working for multiple row results, how to handle that? @JustinCave And thanks for your help :)

Comment: Perhaps you want a `for` loop.  Perhaps you want your procedure to have a `sys_refcursor` as an `out` parameter.  Right now, your procedure isn't actually doing anything so it's a bit hard to guess.  If you want to return a `sys_refcursor` to the caller, you'd be better off using a function rather than a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-01403: no data found

You are getting **NO DATA FOUND** at run time. There is nothing wrong with your procedure code, but when you execute it, the **SELECT..INTO** query fails to **fetch rows** for the **filter predicate** specified.

> where p.pid=q.pid

There are no rows in your table for **pid**=`'p001'`

If you are sure about the error, then you could add `no_data_found` **EXCEPTION** and catch the error.

```
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      <do something>
```

Comment: for p001 there is sale in  october 2015 when I only run the sql query that I've embedded in the procedure, the query returns sales in distinct months. How can I get my procedure to display that?

Answer (score 0):

no data found means your select query not returning any values for 'p001' p_id. And also make sure your select query should return only one row at a time otherwise it will throw an error. Because a variable will holds only one value at a time.

```
create or replace procedure m_pro(
        p_pid in products.pid%type) is
        p_pname products.pname%type;
        p_date purchases.ptime%type;
        p_qty_monthly purchases.qty%type;
        p_amnt_monthly purchases.total_price%type;
        p_avg_price purchases.total_price%type;


    begin
    select pname, p_time, qty_month, amount_month,(amount_month/qty_month) as avg_sale into p_pname,p_date,p_qty_monthly, p_amnt_monthly, p_avg_price
    FROM 
        (select p.pname, to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy') p_time, 
        sum(qty) as qty_month, sum(total_price) as amount_month 
        from products p, purchases q
        where p.pid=q.pid
    group by pname, to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy')) 
    where pname=p_pname;
    dbms_output.put_line ('Product name is:'|| p_pname || 'Purchase date is:' || p_date || 'Units sold per month are/is: ' || p_qty_monthly || 'Monthly sale amount: ' || p_amnt_monthly || 'Average sale price is: ' || p_avg_price);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      dbms_output.Put_line ('No values returned');

    end;
    /
```

Just add exception block before end statement.

**Edit**: Your select query  with p_pid check is

```
   select pname, p_time, qty_month, amount_month,(amount_month/qty_month) as avg_sale 
        FROM 
            (select p.pname, to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy') p_time, 
            sum(qty) as qty_month, sum(total_price) as amount_month 
            from products p, purchases q
            where p.pid=q.pid and p.pid=(some value) -- in procedure p.pid=p_pid
        group by pname, to_char(q.ptime,'MON yyyy')) 
       -- where pname=p_pname remove where pname=p_name
```

Comment: You have a **syntax error** which will raise a compilation error.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Edited the post and removed additional End. Thanks please inform still any errors.

Comment: for p001 there is sale in  october 2015 when I only run the sql query that I've embedded in the procedure, the query returns sales in distinct months. How can I get my procedure to display that?

Comment: the query returns 11 rows in which 1 row pertains the input that I gave i.e p001 @Tarun

Comment: @Tarun I also tried pid at that place but it gave build error as invalid identifier, what should I use over there?

Comment: I guess before group by you have to make that check like where p.pid=q.pid and p.pid=p_pid. Still if you have error?

Comment: @Tarun I tried, same error, invalid identifier when I try to build the procedure

Comment: I removed pname line and now getting this error at execution, builds without errors: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "xxxMyID.TRY", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 1  @Tarun

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96330/discussion-between-sam-keith-and-tarun).

Comment: @SamKeith if you wan to handle more than one row you have to use collections in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any purchases in that month your query won't return any data, so the error you are receiving is a result of that.
Each query needs to return a result or you get the error ORA-1403 No data found.

In your case you should use a left join so you always get a record back from purchases also when there are no records in that table to join with. So your sum will be zero in that case.

Comment: there is sale in  october 2015 for the product and I tried other products too, when I only run the sql query that I've embedded in the procedure, the query returns sales in distinct months. How can I get my procedure to display that?

Comment: the embedded sql query returns 11 rows in which 1 row pertains the input that I gave i.e p001

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use Ref cursor to avoid any kind of worry for handling No Data Found Or Too many Rows Exception. Below snippet will helo you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE m_pro(
    p_pid IN products.pid%type,
    p_lst OUT sys_refcursor) -- Use ref cursor to avoid no data found or too many rows exception
IS
--  p_pname products.pname%type;
--  p_date purchases.ptime%type;
--  p_qty_monthly purchases.qty%type;
--  p_amnt_monthly purchases.total_price%type;
--  p_avg_price purchases.total_price%type;
BEGIN
  OPEN p_lst FOR 
  SELECT pname, 
  p_time, 
  qty_month, 
  amount_month, 
  (amount_month/qty_month)
AS
  avg_sale FROM
  (SELECT p.pname,
    TO_CHAR(q.ptime,'MON yyyy') p_time,
    SUM(qty)         AS qty_month,
    SUM(total_price) AS amount_month
  FROM products p,
    purchases q
  WHERE p.pid=q.pid
  GROUP BY pname,
    TO_CHAR(q.ptime,'MON yyyy')
  ) WHERE P.pid=p_pid;
END;
```

Comment: I'll still have to declare the variables after IS? And give names that are in p_lst? what will be the 2nd parameter when I'll execute the procedure?

Comment: It depends how you are manipulating the result once the sp is executed. If you simply want the output to display then ref cursor is ok.

Comment: If you need to manipulate data once sp is executed then we need to stcik to INTO clause as shown in your post